# Image Count flux slider

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm using [flux slider](http://www.joelambert.co.uk/flux/) to show post attachments in wordpress. I was wondering if I can get the image count of which image is being shown. (e.g. 1 of 7)

```
window._flux = new flux.slider('#content',{pagination: false, autoplay: false, controls:true, transitions: 'dissolve',});
```

the full javascript file is [here](https://github.com/joelambert/Flux-Slider/blob/master/js/flux.jquery.js)